# Overheating & boiling in the overflow tank

Tags: engine

I have had the gases checked in my overflow tank (which boils short distances) and also over heats.

Two different mechanics tested the gases and said it's not the head gasket but yet it still boils in the overflow tank.

It also overheats when the temperature outside starts warming up, this winter I could drive it anywhere and it didn't over heat but now that spring is here its is starting again.

My husband has changed the thermostat twice and radiator cap. I also had the radiator fan replaced.

Do you have any suggestions as to why it's overheating?

Comment: Make, Model, Year, Miles?

Comment: Do you have temp gauge? If so what does it read when you have the boiling in the tank?

Comment: When does it overheat, at idle, highway speeds, or both?

Answer (score 2):

A few options to consider:

- Coolant concentration, but if the mechanics tested the gases to be sure they check the concentration level. Too little antifreeze in relation to water will negatively affect boiling temp.
- radiator is stopped up
- water pump veins warn off causing low coolant flow

Comment: Another thing to look at is the fan relay to ensure it us operating correctly.